# UIKeyboard letter click action in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, keyboard, action

I want to get UIKeyboard's each letter click action in iOS application, 
is it possible in swift?

such as:

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   ...
 }
```

but on the other buttons.. without creating custom keybaord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
//you can check here which key has pressed in parameter 'string'
return true
}
```